# Focus on custom modal only using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and badly stuck at something.

I have a custom modal that pops up on click of a button. This modal contains 2 other buttons. Problem occurs when I start pressing tab button. :(
The focus moves behind the modal screen and user is able to interact with the application which is a strict no no!

I can't use React modal for this one.

Is there a way to make the focus stick to the modal div on top using ReactJS/Javascript.
So far I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Please have a look. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    _focusRestrict() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (this.state.resetLifePlanner) {
            //alert('Called');
            event.stopPropagation();
            const key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

            switch (key) {
            case 9:
                if (document.activeElement.id === 'confirmButton') {
                    console.log('Called if:: move focus to cancelButton');
                    this.cancelButton.focus();
                    //React.findDOMNode(this.refs.cancelButton).focus();
                    //document.getElementById('cancelButton').focus();
                }
                else if (document.activeElement.id === 'cancelButton') {
                    console.log('Called else:: move focus to confirmButton');
                    this.confirmButton.focus();
                    //React.findDOMNode(this.refs.confirmButton).focus();
                    //document.getElementById('confirmButton').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }, true);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._focusRestrict();
}
```

Is there a ReactJS event handling way of doing it?

Also, is there a way to bind the event to the div?

Comment: maybe you have to use event.preventDefault => https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I did add event.preventdefault(). Now default behavior on tabbing is not functioning correctly. Is there a way to resume from e.preventdefault() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `event.stopPropagation();`, just add `event.preventDefault();`

Don't forget to remove your listener when unmounting your modal component. You will have to place the current anonymous fonction in a named fonction.

```
export default class ArtistList extends Component {

    // ...

    componentDidMount() {

        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, true);
    }

    componentWillunmount() {

        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
    }
}



function handleKeydown(e) {

    if (this.state.resetLifePlanner) {
        //alert('Called');
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        const key = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        switch (key) {
        case 9:
            if (document.activeElement.id === 'confirmButton') {
                console.log('Called if:: move focus to cancelButton');
                this.cancelButton.focus();
                //React.findDOMNode(this.refs.cancelButton).focus();
                //document.getElementById('cancelButton').focus();
            }
            else if (document.activeElement.id === 'cancelButton') {
                console.log('Called else:: move focus to confirmButton');
                this.confirmButton.focus();
                //React.findDOMNode(this.refs.confirmButton).focus();
                //document.getElementById('confirmButton').focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed event.stopPropogation(); and added event.preventDefault();

Comment: Hey Although I used event.preventdefault(), it stopped the tabbing default functionality completely. i.e., the other events. Any way to resume from event.preventdefault() in javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right. But we also need to add

```
    // This is needed to properly add and remove the keydown event listener
    this._restrictFocus = _.bind(this._restrictFocus, this);
```

in the constructor of the react component. Otherwise it doesn't seem to work.

Hope this helps.